# Set `width: auto` in flex-direction: column;

Tags: html, css, flexbox, width

I have `div1` with `flex-direction: column`. Inside that div1 I want to have another `div2`.
**I'll be populating** that div2 with **words of different lengths** and I want the `width` to be `auto`(self-adjustable).
But `width: auto` doesn’t work with `flex-direction: column`.
And I want to have `div2` **aligned to the left**.

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  ///////
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I want the same behavior as if `flex-direction` would be set to `row`. **Just like this:**

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

P.S. Cannot use `width: max-content;` and `width: min-content;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `align-items:flex-start` on the parent.

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
align-items: flex-start;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Alternatively, `align-self:start` on the child

```css
.parent {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>
    <span>
      Some text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I do anything without touching the `parent` element?
I can edit only `child` element.
Thanks

Comment: Added another option

Comment: That worked for me. But what if `parent` div is `display: block`? How would you go about that?